rxjs take operator is not working correctly
I am going to set first item's id as selected id in the initial loading.
For this, I used rxjs take operator, but it is not working. Please help me find why it is not working.
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadVariantsBatch());

    this.filteredVariants$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((variants) => {
      console.log(variants.length);
      if (variants.length > 0) {
        this.onSelectVariant(variants[0].id);
      }
    });
  }

I used take(1), but when I log items length, it shows 5 which is the length of the whole item list.

The phrase 'initial loading' needs a bit more info. Do you mean you wish to set the first item's ID as the selected ID for the first emission of the observable, and not do it for the subsequent emissions of the observable?

the tap operator in rxjs dos'nt take the first element from youre data he just take the first data that the observable emit so in youre case the observable emit items array so that waht you get if you want to only get the first element from your items array you can just use the map operator to do that like this:
ngOnInit(): void {
this.store.dispatch(new LoadVariantsBatch());

this.filteredVariants$.pipe(map(variants => variants[0])).subscribe((variants) => {
  console.log(variants.length);
  if (variants.length > 0) {
    this.onSelectVariant(variants[0].id);
  }
});

}
you can read more about take operator here take() operator, good luck!

it works. thanks :)

Learn a little bit more about rxjs and how it works. operators are a base model for changing data stream. So here, a take operator just takes the first emitted value and close a subscription. Seems, you have an array-like first value in the this.filteredVariants$ emitted values.
You have to access by index you need to check concrete values in array-like object.
if (variants[0]?.length > 0) {
    this.onSelectVariant(variants[0].id);
}


The take(1) in your case doesnt make any sense. You can remove it.
take(1) it means from the observable flow will take only 1. Not from the data that will subscribed. So you should check at your own the length of data.
So im assuming that you have an array with strings. The code below should work and you can take only 1, in the index 0.
if (variants.length > 0) {
this.onSelectVariant(variants[0].id);}

